# Which Regex command to use in Notepad++ to find the desired emails?

Tags: command-line, microsoft-word, email, notepad++, regex

I have a lot of txt files in drive D, and drive E. Each file has a lot of different formats. Which Regex ( Notepad++ ) do I need to use, to get the result of email lines with a domain that contains the word " school "? The result example is :

abc@newyork.school.com ...

bca@school.edu.com ...

cab@adschool.ssd.com.bn...

The dots behind are any character. If the characters behind the email that contain the word " school " are still excluded.

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1642378/edit) and add more significant cases with text before and after email, are there only spaces, punctuation marks, really any characters like `%µ$¨&"[{|@`?

Comment: [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)

Answer (score 0):

Find what: `(?s).*?(\S+@\S*school\S*\.\S+)|.+`
Replace with: `$1\n`

Before:
[image]

After:
[image]

[Demo test in regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/98HiA0/1/)

Comment: If the answer helped to solve the problem please check the ✓ symbol next to the answer.